# How to reanimate combination of mathtext (T2) with UTF-8 in pdflatex stopped working after recent updates?

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, miktex, unicode, cyrillic

A minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,notitlepage]{article}

\usepackage[warn]{mathtext}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
Например $А_б$.
\end{document}
```

Log file, first run with example after clear Basic MiKTeX installation, no any user formats, etc.:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6630 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.6.1)  1 JUN 2018 11:44
entering extended mode
**./test18.tex
(test18.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size12.clo"
File: size12.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(C:\Users\vfkom\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\t2\mathtext.sty
Package: mathtext 2018/04/13 v1.1 transparent text-and-math defs
LaTeX Info: Redefining \halign on input line 119.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1enc.def"
File: t1enc.def 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
\symT1letters=\mathgroup4
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\cyrillic\t2aenc.def"
File: t2aenc.def 2005/09/27 v1.0i Cyrillic encoding definition file
Now handling font encoding T2A ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding T2A
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t2aenc.dfu"
File: t2aenc.dfu 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc

! Undefined control sequence.
l.46 \DeclareUnicodeCharacter
                             {00A4}{\textcurrency}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.46 \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0
                               0A4}{\textcurrency}
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.46 \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A4}{\textcurrency
                                                 }
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.47 \DeclareUnicodeCharacter
                             {00A7}{\textsection}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\textsection ->\T1-tmcmd \textsection 
                                      \T1\textsection \T1math\textsection 
l.47 \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A7}{\textsection
                                                }
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 495 strings out of 493305
 5269 string characters out of 3138875
 54363 words of memory out of 3000000
 4120 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 3938 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 5000i,0n,27p,163b,36s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: Which problem do you encounter? Looks correct for me (with fully updated TL2018).

Comment: Completely reinstalled 30.05.2018 fresh MikTeX 2.9 x64 on Windows 10 has error: pdflatex> ! Undefined control sequence. pdflatex> 1.46 \DeclareUnicodeCharacter pdflatex> {00A4}{\textcurrency}

Comment: Is it possible to see the actual log file? You can update your question with it), since you are using MikTeX there is a likelihood that even if you reinstalled, there is still old stuff lurking in your Windows profile, old stuff that overrides the new stuff.

Comment: Looks like you've managed to update your `mathtext` package but not your format: can you do a full update and force rebuilding of the format files?

Comment: Folder in the Program files was completely cleaned before reinstallation, folders in the user profile was not checked. The problems started after the update from the repository, which I did the day before. The previous few months I did not make any LaTeX updates.

Comment: A conflict with also necessary `pscyr` package is also possible, which I later added manually (not from the repository). Although there I have been no such problems so far. After copying the package files, a series of actions were performed, as usual:
p +pscyr.map --> `initexmf --edit-config-file dvips` 
+pscyr.map --> `initexmf --edit-config-file pdftex`
Map pscyr.map --> `initexmf --edit-config-file updmap`
`updmap`
f pscyr2.map --> `initexmf --edit-config-file dvipdfm`
`initexmf -u`
Refresh FNDB
`mkfntmap`

Comment: @JosephWright I'll try to do force rebuilding...

Comment: @VasiliyKomarov FWIW, I just tried your example before and after updating `t2`. I see no difference at all. On my TeX Live distribution, `tlmgr` did a format rebuild. Probably MiKTeX didn't.

Comment: You probably have user formats. Such formats must be recreated in user mode, call `initexmf -dump` on a (user) command line. Also ensure that you checked for updates as user and as admin.

Comment: I tried to run this example with clean installation (no old folders in the system before installation, no any additional customization, Basic MiKTeX only). The result is the same, updated log in topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was solved by doing a thorough update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved after yet another launch of (redesigned) MiKTeX console with updates and refreshing again (the cause of the problem was not understood). Thanks to everyone who paid attention.